# How to sense smartphones nearby?

Tags: wifi, analytics, sensors, smartphone

How does euclid analytics (http://euclidanalytics.com/product/how/) get the mac addresses of nearby smartphones? (Turning wifi ap into a smartphone sensor !)  Do I need to do some instrumentation work on the wifi AP? Or is there another way can achieve the same goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you can sniff wireless packets, you can see every wifi device, what is communicating ( except if its in sniffer mode too ), so basically they scanning for wifi signals, what you can see, but just if wifi  and scanning is turned on the phone.

take a look at [Kismet](http://www.kismetwireless.net/)

but you myght need a wireless card what can go into sniffing mode

Comment: How about using scapy? http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/introduction.html

Comment: did not know that, i will put it into my script library. thx!